# Resume killed job

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, process, kill

I accidentally closed a terminal window where I had limited the cpu usage of a parallel job. Now, if I `ps -e S` in a new terminal window, I can see that job as:

```
 311029 pts/0    TN+  275:25 jobname
```

Is there a way to resume it? I have tried `fg`, `bg`, `jobs` but I am not sure what those commands do and in any case they don't resume the job.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but if I have long-running terminal jobs, I like to use `screen` to protect them from closing the terminal. Run `screen`, then start your command. Close the terminal if you want to. Run `screen -R` from another terminal to get control back.

Answer (score 5):

The `TN+` in the output you show for `ps` indicates three things.  These three characters are "process flags" which each show a characteristic of the shown process.  The full list can be found on the manual page for `ps` in section 7.  In relevant part, they are:

> `T`    stopped by job control signal 
> `N`    low-priority (nice to other users) 
> `+`    is in the foreground process group

The relevant flag here is `T` which is indicating the job is stopped.  Because the process is not assigned to the terminal you're currently using, it's for most practical purposes not easily possible to shunt the process over to another terminal, but you may be able to wake the suspended process up long enough for it to notice its terminal has gone away- which it should have noticed when it was sent `SIGHUP` when it's terminal actually *went* away.

First, try to resume the process with `SIGCONT`:

```
$ kill -CONT 311029
```

Second, whether or not that works, you can reassert its homeless state by manually sending `SIGHUP` and hoping it properly cleans up after itself:

```
$ kill -HUP 311029
```

The reason `fg` and `jobs` are not acting upon the process is that your current shell does not have any ownership of the process in question- it is (or rather it *was*) owned by another (long since dead) shell process.

Comment: Upon `kill -HUP 311029` from a new terminal, the main job in the terminal that originally launched all jobs was killed with:

`Error waiting for execution message in process 3
Segmentation fault (core dump created)
username$ Error waiting for execution message in process 2 
Error waiting for execution message in process 1`


Process `311029` is not listed anymore in the main terminal window if I `ps -e S`.